# Reference for typescript parent or its child class in Angular HTML template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, inheritance

I have a problem with typescript inheritance and property reference in Angular HTML template and couldn't solve it for a long time. (if it's question duplication, sorry for that, I couldn't find question like this).

So I have a parent interface, let it call DummyParent with some properties.

```
export interface DummyParent {
    dummy1?: string;
    dummy2?: number;
}
```

And I have two children of this interface.

```
export interface DummyChild1 extends DummyParent {
    foo1?: string;
    bar1: number;
}
export interface DummyChild2 extends DummyParent {
    foo2?: string;
    bar2: number;
}
```

And I have an Angular component, which get an input and it's type can be a copy of all of these interfaces.

```
@Input() dummy!: DummyParent | DummyChild1 | DummyChild2;
```

But when I have a reference in HTML template for a DummyChild property, I got an error.
For example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dummy.foo1"></ng-container> 
Error: Property 'foo1' does not exist on type 'DummyParent'.
```

Based on this error, seems that dummy property is just a DummyParent object, and I can't reference as a DummyChild1 or DummyChild2 object. **My question is that, how should I instantiate @Input() dummy to be a typeof DummyParent OR DummyChild1 OR DummyChild2.**
I know that I can solve the problem with using object type 'any' or casting object in HTML template like this
<ng-container *ngIf="$any(dummy).foo1">
but i try to avoid using these solutions.
Thanks a lot for any answers.

Answer (score 3):

This is how TS unions work:

```js
export interface DummyParent {
    dummy1?: string;
    dummy2?: number;
}

export interface DummyChild1 extends DummyParent {
    foo1?: string;
    bar1: number;
}
export interface DummyChild2 extends DummyParent {
    foo2?: string;
    bar2: number;
}

type Union = DummyParent | DummyChild1 | DummyChild2

declare var union: Union;

// only dumm1 and dummy2 are available
union.dummy1
union.dummy2
```

`union` allows you to use common properties from all dummy types. Because each type extends `DummyParent` you are allowed to use only properties from `DummyParent`.

In order to make it safe, you should use custom [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```js
export interface DummyParent {
    dummy1?: string;
    dummy2?: number;
}

export interface DummyChild1 extends DummyParent {
    foo1?: string;
    bar1: number;
}
export interface DummyChild2 extends DummyParent {
    foo2?: string;
    bar2: number;
}

type Union = DummyParent | DummyChild1 | DummyChild2

declare var union: Union;

// only dumm1 and dummy2 are available
union.dummy1
union.dummy2


const isOne = (union: Union): union is DummyChild1 => 'bar1' in union
const isTwo = (union: Union): union is DummyChild2 => 'bar2' in union

if(isOne(union)){
    union.bar1 // ok
}

if(isTwo(union)){
    union.bar2 // ok
}
```

Then, I assume you can do smth like that:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isTwo(union)">
 // do smth with union.bar2
</ng-container>
```

P.S. I'm not 100% sure that `in` operator is the best solution for such kind of typeguard.
You can also consider this:

```js
const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is that, how should I instantiate @Input() dummy to be a
> typeof DummyParent OR DummyChild1 OR DummyChild2.

That's what you're currently doing. If you're saying something is either type A, type B or type C you can only acces the properties that exist on ALL THREE types. Otherwise, what would be the point of explicit typing if you could still access non-existent properties?

And since in your cases B and C inherit after A, it will be only properties of type A. If you want to access properties of type A, you have narrow the type to A (e.g. by using type guard).

You can read more about it in the official TypeScript docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).